# Pandas - Column as a dictionary - How to extract always the first element

Tags: python, pandas

I've a pandas dataframe that have the following column:

```
{'date': '2020-04-16T09:00:00', 'is_recurring': True, 'lang': 'en', 'string': 'every day at 9am', 'timezone': None}
{'date': '2020-04-16', 'is_recurring': False, 'lang': 'en', 'string': 'Apr 16', 'timezone': None}
None
```

What I am trying to do is to do is to get always the first position of the date.

Basically I am trying to get the following output:

```
'2020-04-16T09:00:00'
'2020-04-16'
None
```

I try this `print(df['column'].str.split(",")[0])` but I got 'None' and I think it is not the best way to retrieve the desired output

Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: **Please provide a [mcve].** Where does this data come from? _What I am trying to do is to do is to get always the first position of the date._ What do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As 'column' is a dictionary, try this:

```
    for x in df['column']:
        print(x['date'])
```

Another way doing that, is using method 'apply',

```
    print(df.column.apply(lambda x: x['date']))
```

or 'map',

```
    print(df.column.map(lambda x: x['date']))
```

However, if what you want is the first element of the dictionary, whatever it is, then it would be better to get the first element in a list of values ​​returned by it, like this:

```
    print(df.column.map(lambda x: list(x.values())[0]))
```

remembering that a python dictionary is a collection of unordered elements, identified by a key, so i think the code above is meaningless.

Regards.